# Different functions or same functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have a question in my booklet :

> **$f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ and $f(x) = 1$ are different or not why or why not?**

I can only think that the functions are different because the second one is a constant function irrespective of the value of $x$.

But on evaluating the first function we will always get $1$. and in the first function is undefined at $x = 0$ while the second function is defined at $x = 0$.

Is there any other way of thinking it mathematically and my instructor never covered anything related to this. Kindly help.

Comment: The functions have the same range (they both take on the value $1$ identically) but as you noted the first one is obviously undefined at $x=0$ so the functions have different domains. If you restrict the domain of the second one to exclude $0$ then they are the same function, otherwise no.

Comment: You need to specify a domain. If the domain does not include $0$ then both are the same. If the domain does include $0$, then you need to specify what $0 \over 0$ means.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I think you should  write it as an answer (elaborating a bit) so that I can accept it.

Comment: @user109256 sure, but is Max's answer below not sufficient? It's essentially what I'd write anyway. Youd have to be more specific on what you'd want me to elaborate on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two functions are identical if they have the same domain, and if they have the same functional values at every point in that domain.
If $ f(x) = \frac{x}{x} $ and $ g(x) = 1 $, then f(x) = g(x) for all x within the domain of f, but as LoveTooNap29 pointed out, their domains are different.  Therefore the functions are not identical.

Comment: Nothing in the OP actually says that the domains of $f$ and $g$ are different. It's up to speculation, the only thing that's clear is that $f$ must not have $0$ in its domain, but what either of the functions _does_ have in its domain would first need to be specified.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: At OP's level, functions have a domain of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \text{all the values at which the function is undefined}$ unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @Deusovi: perhaps, but IMO that's a pretty big failure of education then. It should be made clear early on that real-valued functions are very much just a special case – important, but by no means a sensible “default for everything”.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you phrase the question. If you say

> Let $f,g : \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{Q}$, $$f(x) = \frac{x}{x}, \qquad g(x)=1$$

then $f$ and $g$ are in fact equal. This is also true if you replace the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ with the reals, or with complex numbers... as long as you do it consistently for both functions.

However, because $g$ doesn't actually use its argument, there's no reason to assume its domain should be $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$. I could write

> Let $g : \{1, 2, (0,5), i,\mathrm{cucumber}\} \to \mathbb{R}$, $$g(x)=1$$

or, more reasonably, just

> Let $g : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$, $$g(x)=1.$$

Then, $g$ would be a completely different *kind of object* from $f$, and depending on your philosophy they would either be nonequal or it wouldn't even make sense to ask whether they're equal.

Answer (score 1):

note that $$\frac{x}{x}=1$$ if $$x\ne 0$$ and $$1=1$$ for all real $$x$$

Comment: This only proves the ranges are equal so the functions are equal everywhere they are defined. The domains remain different, however, so theyre technically different functions.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, $f(x)=x/x$ does not equal $g(x)=1$, because $f(x)$ is technically undefined at 0. In the same way, the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) technically does not equal $\sin(x)/x$.

However this is merely a technicality: the limit at 0 exists, and you can redefine $f(x)$ to equal its limit at 0, in which case $f(x)=g(x)=1$. Usually, this is exactly what you should do.